# Pandas df.itertuples renaming dataframe columns when printing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I know that normally pandas' itertuples() will return the values of each including the column names as follows:

```
ab=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3,3]),columns=['hi','low','med'])
for i in ab.itertuples():
    print(i)
```

and the output is as follows:

```
Pandas(Index=0, hi=0.05421443, low=0.2456833, med=0.491185)
Pandas(Index=1, hi=0.28670429, low=0.5828551, med=0.279305)
Pandas(Index=2, hi=0.53869406, low=0.3427290, med=0.750075)
```

However, I have no idea why it doesn't shows the columns as I expected for my another set of code as below:

```
            us qqq equity  us spy equity
date                                    
2017-06-19            0.0            1.0
2017-06-20            0.0           -1.0
2017-06-21            0.0            0.0
2017-06-22            0.0            0.0
2017-06-23            1.0            0.0
2017-06-26            0.0            0.0
2017-06-27           -1.0            0.0
2017-06-28            1.0            0.0
2017-06-29           -1.0            0.0
2017-06-30            0.0            0.0
```

the above is a Pandas Dataframe with Timestamp as index, float64 as the values in the list, and a list of string ['us qqq equity','us spy equity'] as the columns.

When I do this:

```
for row in data.itertuples():
    print (row)
```

It shows the columns as _1 and _2 as follows:

```
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-19 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=1.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-20 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=-1.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-22 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-23 00:00:00'), _1=1.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-26 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-27 00:00:00'), _1=-1.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-28 00:00:00'), _1=1.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-29 00:00:00'), _1=-1.0, _2=0.0)
Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-30 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=0.0)
```

Does anyone has any clue about what have I done wrong? Does it have to do with some variable referencing issue when creating the original dataframe? (Also, as a side question, I learnt from the community that the type of data generated from itertuples() should be tuples, but it seems (as shown above), the return type is  as I verified from the type statement?)

Thank you for all your patience as I am still trying to master the application of DataFrame.

Comment: What does `data.columns` says?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
It says `Index(['us qqq equity', 'us spy equity'], dtype='object')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with handling column names having spaces in them. If you replace the column names with different ones without spaces, it will work:

```
df.columns = ['us_qqq_equity', 'us_spy_equity'] 
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\s+', '_')  # Courtesy @MaxU  
for r in df.head().itertuples():
    print(r)

# Pandas(Index='2017-06-19', us_qqq_equity=0.0, us_spy_equity=1.0)
# Pandas(Index='2017-06-20', us_qqq_equity=0.0, us_spy_equity=-1.0)
# ...
```

Column names with spaces cannot effectively be represented in named tuples, so they are renamed automatically when printing.

Comment: We can use a bit more flexible way to rename columns: `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\s+', '_')`

Comment: @ COLDSPEED
That is very amazing. Hardly would I figure it out myself. My follow-up question would be is this a bug or it is a normal behavior? Basically what is the type of data returned by itertuples() to be precise? It shows `<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>` yet everyone here says tuple (or named tuple which I am not familiar with). Can anyone explain to me what is this type of data and why this type of data does not take space?

Comment: @user7786493 I am not 100% what type it is, but I am almost positive it is a flavour of [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and this is an inherent limitation of those.

Comment: Although the MaxU fix  works for embedded spaces, the problem still happens with trailing spaces in the source Excel -e.g.  "us_qqq_equity ".      I fixed it with this line before the replace: df.columns = [item.strip() for item in df.columns.values]

Comment: A bit late to this thread, but just to add an additional detail. Besides the issue with spaces, the names are also not retained when the column name starts with a non-letter character, such as a number (e.g. "5m_res" or underscore (e.g. "_name").

Answer (score 4):

Interesting observation: out of `DataFrame.iterrows()`, `DataFrame.iteritems()`, `DataFrame.itertuples()` only the last one renames the columns, containing spaces:

```
In [140]: df = df.head(3)

In [141]: list(df.iterrows())
Out[141]:
[(Timestamp('2017-06-19 00:00:00'), us qqq equity    0.0
  us spy equity    1.0
  Name: 2017-06-19 00:00:00, dtype: float64),
 (Timestamp('2017-06-20 00:00:00'), us qqq equity    0.0
  us spy equity   -1.0
  Name: 2017-06-20 00:00:00, dtype: float64),
 (Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'), us qqq equity    0.0
  us spy equity    0.0
  Name: 2017-06-21 00:00:00, dtype: float64)]

In [142]: list(df.iteritems())
Out[142]:
[('us qqq equity', date
  2017-06-19    0.0
  2017-06-20    0.0
  2017-06-21    0.0
  Name: us qqq equity, dtype: float64), ('us spy equity', date
  2017-06-19    1.0
  2017-06-20   -1.0
  2017-06-21    0.0
  Name: us spy equity, dtype: float64)]

In [143]: list(df.itertuples())
Out[143]:
[Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-19 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=1.0),
 Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-20 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=-1.0),
 Pandas(Index=Timestamp('2017-06-21 00:00:00'), _1=0.0, _2=0.0)]
```

Comment: Agree. Thanks for @MaxU pointing it out. The reason I am focusing on itertuples() (Please correct me if I am wrong) is because the looping time should be the shortest among the 3 options if we are trying to iterate over rows of a dataframe. Unless there are other faster alternatives?

Comment: @user7786493, you are welcome. The fastest way to process data in Pandas is to use __vectorized__ methods/functions and to avoid using `for loops`, `.apply()`, `.applymap()`, etc.

Comment: Nice one. Also, @user7786493 I agree with Max. If you are applying operations on all elements, I suggest you use apply/transform/map.

Comment: Agree. I am fully aware of vectorized functions/methods provided by df. However, it is not always the case that a vectorized functions/methods can achieve my goal especially when multiple conditions/logics are required in producing a new set of values. For example, if a new column has to depends on the existing columns of the dataframe (achievable via vectorized operations at this stage) AND also depends on the value of its last previous row of this new column.

Comment: `hi hi        low low     med med
    0  0.836905  0.744606  0.413051
    1  0.045912  0.442163  0.393753
    2  0.806727  0.742776  0.794056`

Using this example, what if I want to add a new column ('answer') that shows the boolean value of (sum of low low and med med of each row )>the previous row of the new column ('answer'), assuming the first value of answer start with 0?

Comment: @user7786493, i'd suggest you to open a new question with a small reproducible data set and a desired data set and a short description of what you want to achieve. SO community might find a vectorized solution for it (or not)...

Comment: @MaxU Yes. I will open a new topic now.